# How can I identify the purpose of a process called "analog"?

Tags: memory-usage, top

I had an unusual amount of memory being used in the server and when I logged in as root and ran "top" I got this line:

```
13778 global    34  19 1726m 857m  336 D  1.3 85.6   1:49.89 analog
```

Anyone know what the "analog" command means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program named `analog` eats your memory.

Run `ps auxwww | grep [a]nalog` as root. This will give you path to the binary. This can give you some information (if it is in `/opt/somepackage/bin/analog`) or it may not (if it's in `/usr/bin`). If your distribution is rpm-based you can run `rpm -qf /path/to/file` to determine package to which the file belongs. Then `rpm -qi packagename` will give you package description.

It is also possible that somebody compiled some code, named the resulting binary analog and run it. Binary name doesn't tell much.

Comment: It's an analog stats program gone awry. We had an issue with google endlessly crawling a poorly built link on a site and it seems analog stats just picked it up and went nuts on it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [cPanel process](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/AnalogStats) to monitor your website's traffic.

Trace with: `ls -l /proc/13778`